# Ebike 24v relay board - switch?

Tags: relay, board, 24v

Hi I’m building an Ebike and using a reclaimed relay board from an old electric moped. My question is the relay board has 3 small wires presumably for the switch, but this confuses me as I only need 2 for a switch. See picture:
Also why use 8 relays.
Extra info, 1500w hub motor, 2x12v 40ah batteries.
Any advise would be great.[image]

Comment: An electric moped would use a throttle (probably a potentiometer) to give variable speed control. A switch wouldn't. I have no idea what's going on with the relays.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try a petentiometer.

Comment: No, try a potentiometer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a 3 wire throttle controller

[image: diagram]

This board might already consider variable speeds.
As for having multiple relays, maybe it has some relay logic going on which creates a stepped output to the motor based on the wire's inputs.
You might be able to give a straight signal to the 24V circuit if you want to use a switch, but if you want variable acceleration, I would recommend buying a throttle control.

Image credits: https://support.electricscooterparts.com/support/discussions/topics/1000083529